# Install OmniPay without Composer

Tags: php, omnipay

I don't want to use composer to install Omnipay but rather use traditional PHP includes to setup Omnipay with Stripe.

How do i do this? I have extracted it to this folder:

```
www.mysite.com/payments/src
```

Stripe.php with example code is here:

```
www.mysite.com/payments/Stripe.php
```

Where do i put the stripe payment gateway files? 
What PHP files do i need to include in the header example code?

I am using this example code:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/payments/src/Omnipay/Omnipay.php";

use Omnipay\Omnipay;

$gateway = Omnipay::create('Stripe');
$gateway->setApiKey('abc123');

$formData = ['number' => '4242424242424242', 'expiryMonth' => '6', 'expiryYear' => '2016', 'cvv' => '123'];
$response = $gateway->purchase(['amount' => '10.00', 'currency' => 'USD', 'card' => $formData])->send();

if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
    // payment was successful: update database
    print_r($response);
} elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
    // redirect to offsite payment gateway
    $response->redirect();
} else {
    // payment failed: display message to customer
    echo $response->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to go that way, but if you really want to why not just install it with composer in another location and then copy the files (including the composer autoload file) in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running xampp on Windows and initially I didn't want to use composer either but once composer is installed then all I needed to do was to create the composer.json file in the project directory with the code below and in cmd change path to the project directory and type composer install.

```
{
    "require": {
        "omnipay/stripe": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

I could then see why a manual installation is not documented because it automatically installed the all the following dependancies and configured the autoload files vendor/composer/:

```
vendor/autoload.php
vendor/composer
vendor/guzzle
vendor/omnipay/common
vendor/omnipay/stripe
vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher
vendor/symfony/http-foundation
vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring
composer.lock
```